# Comparing x amount of tuples and printing out duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, tuples

I have a dataframe with one column containing a list of tuples with varying lengths that represent product codes with each contract number being the index. The lengths of the tuples vary between 1 and 22. I have used `groupby()` to group tuples of the same length.

I used `df.get_group()` to access dataframes for each length. The amount of rows for each df varies from 1 to 80.

For example for the tuples (123, 456, 789) and (123, 456, 213), I'd like the output to be:
`[1]: (123, 456)`

From here I would like to compare each tuple to the x amount of others in the dataframe and print out all of the duplicate items.

I've tried using `set(x) & set(y)` but I am not sure how to use this for an x amount of rows.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try merging all the tuples in a group together into one series, and grabbing the duplicates with [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html#pandas-series-duplicated):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'tuples': [(136, 629, 694), (136, 273, 208),
                              (640, 139, 405, 884, 734),
                              (123, 456, 789),
                              (492, 829, 451, 315, 804),
                              (123, 456, 213), (142, 569, 636, 380),
                              (924, 808, 330, 489, 658),
                              (538, 163, 669, 817), (569, 780),
                              (230, 569), (278, 509, 718, 817)]})


def get_duplicates(s):
    # Convert Tuples into a Series
    s = pd.Series(s.sum())
    # Filter duplicated and convert back to tuple
    return tuple(s[s.duplicated()])


# Groupby len and apply function
duplicate_tuples = df.groupby(
    df['tuples'].map(len)
)['tuples'].apply(get_duplicates).reset_index(name='duplicate_values')

# For Display
print(duplicate_tuples.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
tuples duplicate_values
     2           (569,)
     3  (136, 123, 456)
     4           (817,)
     5               ()
```